# How do I access the nth item in a dictionary or hash?

Tags: language-agnostic, dictionary, hashmap

I have a dictionary of keys and values, for example:

```
{
    fred: 1,
    dave: 2,
    lily: 3
}
```

How do I get the 2nd element in the dictionary - `{dave:2}` in this case?

---

Background: I've seen this question asked so many times on SO in one form or another, 
so I thought I'd write a Q&A page as a community wiki that folks can be
referred to and which might hopefully become the canonical answer for this question.

This Q&A applies to dictionaries as they are implemented in many different
languages. Different languages use different names to refer to what is
essentially the same data structure - for example they're called hashes in
Perl, dictionaries in Python. In Objective-C they're instances of the
`NSDictionary` or `NSMutableDictionary` classes.

Comment: Not necessarily a bad idea, but see the [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq): "It's also perfectly fine to ask and answer your own question, as long as you pretend you're on Jeopardy: phrase it in the form of a question."

Comment: Ah, thanks Cody - I'll reword

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In a nutshell, you can't - because dictionaries are *unordered* 
collections of key/value pairs. The order in which you populate a dictionary 
is not retained in memory. Here's a simple example in Python:

```
>>> dict = { 'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 3 }
>>> dict # show the value of dict in memory
{'a': 1, 'c': 3, 'b': 2}
```

As you can see, although the dictionary is initialised with keys in 
the order a, b, c, printing the value of the dictionary shows them
ordered a, c, b. Even that ordering is not retained in memory; 
as you add more key/value pairs to a dictionary the ordering in the 
above expression will continue to change.

### Why is this?

Dictionaries are optimised for fast storage and retrieval of a value
based on a unique key. The implementation varies from one language to the
next but typically it works something like this:

- the dictionary is backed by a standard array of N elements
- on storing a key/value pair, the key is put through a function that 
  transforms it into an integer (a "hashing function" - hence the name 
  "hash" for this data structure in Perl). A simple hashing function
  for ASCII string keys might be to add up the ASCII values of each 
  character. (Note: that's not a *good* hashing algorithm - just an
  example of a simple one!)
- the integer is then divided by the size of the array, and the remainder
  of that division is used as an index into the array
- if the array element at that index is already populated then
  one of a variety of techniques is used to resolve the clash (e.g.
  the contents of the array element are themselves an array to which
  the new value along with its unhashed key are appended)
- retrieval works in the same way as storage: take the key, use it to
  derive an array index, then retrieve the value associated with that
  key
- the backing array can be resized as the dictionary grows: on resizing
  the array, each element in the dictionary has its hash value divided by
  the new array size, resulting in a new remainder, i.e. a new location 
  in the backing array.

Answer (score 1):

I am newbie here, so can not add a comment yet.....But this is actually a comment to the above answer by Simon.

Useful Question & Nice Answer, Simon. You could have added another section to the answer, saying, *Hence, the only way this question makes sense is, if we take an approach like the following examples*

- sort(dict) and then obtain the n-th item of this new sorted dictionary.  This will produce the exact same dictionary n-th item every time, even if the underlying array grows.
- enumerate( dict ) and obtain the n-th key in the dictionary