# How to sort a Dictionary<string,Dictionary<int,string>> by int in the Value part

Tags: sorting, c#-4.0, dictionary

I'm trying to sort a Dictionary with string as key, and another Dictionary as value(which contains int as key and string as value) by int in second dictionary(i.e. value). I was clueless in this task, help me out.

Comment: A dictionary [is not sorted](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6384710/why-is-a-dictionary-not-ordered). So either your question is pointless or you should show what you have tried. Maybe we can suggest a different approach.

Comment: first element can contain {1, 3, 4}, second{1, 2, 5}. How to sort?

Comment: all my int values are unique. Ex. <"A",<1,"abd">>, <"C",<3,"asd">>,<"X",<2,"sdl">> like this. what I wanted is sorted Dictionary. like A,X,C sort of this.

Comment: @user3774358, why are you using dictionary in this case? It is nonsense.\