# linq group by and count

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq

```
select  uc.adminid, count(*)
from Users uc
join UsersMessage ucm on uc.admincallid = ucm.admincallid
where uc.CallDate between '2016-08-01' and '2016-09-01' and ucm.type = 4
group by uc.adminid
order by count(*)
```

And here is what I've tried:

```
 public static Dictionary<int, int> ReturnSomething(int month)
        {

            Dictionary<int, int> dict = new Dictionary<int, int>();
            using (DataAccessAdapter adapter = new DataAccessAdapter())
            {
                LinqMetaData meta = new LinqMetaData(adapter);
                dict = (from uc in meta.Users
                        join ucm in meta.meta.UsersMessage on uc.AdminCallId equals ucm.AdminCallId 
                        where ucm.type == 4 && uc.CallDate.Month == month
                        group uc by uc.AdminId into g
                        select new { /* ???? adminid = g. */ }).ToDictionary(x => new Dictionary<int, int>(/* ????? x, x.Name*/));
            }

            return dict;
        }
```

how can I achieve what I need?

Comment: *how can I achieve what I need?* And what is your need?

Comment: To return what my sql query is returning

Comment: you need `g.Key` and `g.Count()`. Have look at [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7285714/linq-with-groupby-and-count).

Comment: Check the documentation for group by result (`IGrouping<TKey, TElement>`). For instance, you have `g.Key`, `g.Count()` etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The key of the dictionary is the key of the `GroupBy` and the value is the `Count()`, so you need:

```
// ...
.ToDictionary(g => g.Key, g => g.Count()); // key is AdminCallId and value how often this Id occured
```

Since you've asked how to order it decending:

You are building a dictionary which has no order(well, It should read: it is non-deterministic). So the ordering is 
completely unnecessary. Why it's unordered? [Read this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6384710/why-is-a-dictionary-not-ordered)

But if you would create something else and you wanted to know how to order by `Count DESC` you could use this:

```
from uc in meta.Users
join ucm in meta.meta.UsersMessage on uc.AdminCallId equals ucm.AdminCallId 
where ucm.type == 4 && uc.CallDate.Month == month
group uc by uc.AdminId into g
orderby g.Count() descending
select new { adminid = g.Key, count = g.Count() })
```

Comment: Yep, it works. Btw, if I want to order descending by Count(), how to change my static function?

Comment: @FlorinM.: you are building a dictionary which has no order(well, It should read: it is non-deterministic). So the ordering is 
completely unnecessary. Why it's unordered? [Read this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6384710/why-is-a-dictionary-not-ordered)

Comment: What if I do want to count only those entries with some distinct field value ( eg.: LinkedId ) ? I did try something like this but it doesn't work as expecteD: select new { adminid = g.Key, count = g.Select(x => x.LinkedId).Distinct().Count() }

Comment: @FlorinM.: what means it did not work? YOu want to count distinct ID's or you want only entries which have unique `LinkedId`? In the former case your apporach should work.