# Dictionary not preserving order if removed key is added later

Tags: c#, .net

I experienced a very **strange** **issue** with **dictionary**. To my understanding, **dictionary** always preserve **insertion** **order**. If I try to add previously **removed** **key** again, it is getting added at the **top** instead of getting added at the **end**. Is it a known **bug**?

```
            Dictionary<char, int> dic = new Dictionary<char, int>();

            dic.Add('b', 1);
            dic.Add('c', 1);
            dic.Add('a', 1);

            dic.Remove('b');

            dic.Add('b', 1); // b is getting added at index 0
```

Comment: No, it's not a bug. If you want to guarantee order use an OrderedDictionary. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6384710/why-is-a-dictionary-not-ordered

Comment: Dictionary does not guarantee order. This does not mean that it will shuffle everything you give it. It _might_ preserve order sometimes, but how it works exactly is an implementation detail. Therefore, you should assume that dictionary entries are unordered.